# Car having issues when starting with key, but starter motor does work

Tags: starting, vw, golf

Car always starts perfectly when using a screwdriver to connect terminals on starter motor.

When using the key, however, only the lights come on, starter motor doesn't even click.

But when using the key a short while after having driven the car for a bit, it works again.

Summary: Starter motor seems fine. Key does work, but not when car has been standing for probably around 2 hours.

Car is a 1996 VW Citi Golf 1.3

Comment: Could this be a clutch or neutral switch thats bad, so the key-starter circuit is disabled?

Comment: Have you checked anything else other than starter function and battery power?